# duplicate symbol: rust_begin_unwind when mixing rust and c

Tags: c++, c, rust

I have the following situation:

I would like to mix rust and c in my bare-metal microcontroller project. For this reason I don't use cargo but directly call rustc and use it in my own build-system.

I have one rust library that I only want to call from c:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
#![crate_type="lib"]

#[panic_handler]
fn my_panic(_info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_sample_lib_for_c(a: i8) -> i8 {
    return a+53;
}
```

I compile this library like this

```
rustc --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf -C panic=abort -C opt-level=3 --emit obj --crate-type staticlib src/rust_sample_lib_for_c.rs -o src/librust_sample_lib_for_c.a
```

Additionally I have a second independent rust library similar to the one above which is compiled with the same rustc command.

However when I want to link the c sources and both rust libraries I get the following error:

```
ld.lld: error: duplicate symbol: rust_begin_unwind
```

Seems rust_begin_unwind is defined in both statically compiled libraries. I looked into the libs with objdump and indeed in both static compiled libraries there is the rust_begin_unwind symbol.

How can I avoid having multiple defined rust_begin_unwind symbols when compiling indepentent rust libraries that should be called from c?

The panic handler function needs to be defined in each libs otherwise they don't compile.

Comment: PLease refer: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/linking-errors-when-the-c-standard-library-itself-contains-rust-code-using-std-redox/5656

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now solved it with a hack using "objcopy --redefine-sym". Not sure if that is the right way to do it though...

Comment: If you solved it, you can answer your own question and try to help others like you that may encounter the same issue

Comment: I solved it, but as I already mentioned I am not sure if this is the right way to solve this. To me it looks more like a hack tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix this with what rust toolchain supplies, but you could unpack both of the static libraries, remove one copy of Rust runtime libs and link them all together one more time using `-r (partial link)` argument to th e linker command line